# What level of water/dust protection will a silicone case provide?

Tags: equipment-protection, dust, environmental-dangers, weather-sealing, camera-cases

As far as I know, the entry level cameras (like EOS650D or D3200) do not have water/dust protection.

Surfing the internet, I found that there are silicone cases exist for cameras.

So, is it worth to by this case?

What is the level of camera protection does it give? Will I be able to shoot e.g. as waves are clashing rocks?

Comment: Buy a Pentax if you want to spend a similar amount on a DSLR and want water protection.

Comment: @dpollitt Actually, I already have EOS650D, and pretty happy with it. I just was looking for something useful for owner of D5000 as a present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't link to any specific product but from what I can find by googling "650d silicone case" those products provide no water/dust protection whatsoever.

The big opening in the camera that let dust/water in are, in order of importance:

1. The lens mount
2. The battery door
3. Various connectors (USB etc.)
4. Buttons and dials

Any case that only covers some of the buttons is absolutely worthless for water/dust protection.

The silicon cases may provide some very small level of protection if you drop your camera, but considering that DSLRs are pretty rugged and the cases don't protect the biggest weak spot of the camera (the lens/ lens mount) I believe they are probably completely useless.